# Do we need to test findAll methods in Unit Tests?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, mocking

I have the following service method:

```
public List<LabelDTO> findAllByLanguage(Language language) {
    final Map<Pair<UUID, String>, List<TextLabelTranslatable>> valueList = 
        translatableRepository.findAllTranslatable();
    
    // code omitted 

    return labelDTOList;
}
```

I am trying to create the following Unit Test for this method:

```
@Test
public void demo_test() {

    List<LabelWithTranslatable> labelWithTranslatableList = new ArrayList<>();

    LabelWithTranslatable labelWithTranslatable1 = mock(LabelWithTranslatable.class);
    labelWithTranslatable1.getEntity().setId(123L);
    labelWithTranslatableList.add(labelWithTranslatable1);

    LabelWithTranslatable labelWithTranslatable2 = mock(LabelWithTranslatable.class);
    labelWithTranslatable2.getEntity().setId(456L);
    labelWithTranslatableList.add(labelWithTranslatable2);

    // translatableRepository.findAllTranslatable() returns "List<LabelWithTranslatable>"
    when(translatableRepository.findAllTranslatable())
        .thenReturn(labelWithTranslatableList);

    List<LabelDTO> result = labelService.findAllByLanguage(SupportedLanguage.en);


    // assertions
}
```

My questions are:

***1.*** Do we need to test `findAll()` methods in Unit Tests? If so, should we create multiple records to the list and then compare the returned result by the expected filtered values?

***2.*** I mock `LabelWithTranslatable`, but it has an entity and its value is null (`labelWithTranslatable1.getEntity()`). So, how should I mock that entity? Here is the relation:

***LabelWithTranslatable:***

```
public interface LabelWithTranslatable extends 
                     GenericTranslatable<Label, LabelTranslatable> {
}
```

***GenericTranslatable:***

```
public interface GenericTranslatable<E extends BaseEntity, T extends BaseTranslatableEntity> {
    E getEntity();

    T getTranslatable();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you do need to test your `findAllXxx` methods -- the code represented by the `//code omitted` comment in your question needs test coverage.

As you suggest, you can do this by mocking the underlying repository.

To mock your `LabelWithTranslatable` instances you'll need to do:

```java
LabelWithTranslatable labelWithTranslatable1 = mock(LabelWithTranslatable.class);
Label label1 = mock(Label.class);
when(label1.getId()).thenReturn(123L);
when(labelWithTranslatable1.getEntity()).thenReturn(label1);
labelWithTranslatableList.add(labelWithTranslatable1);
```

Comment: Perfect!.. Thanks a lot. What about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69296737/uuid-cannot-be-returned-by-tostring-error-in-unit-test ?