# UUID cannot be returned by toString() error in Unit Test

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mocking, uuid

I have the following Unit Test code bloc where I need to mock the `UUID` of label. As `UUID` cannot be set directly for that class, I need to mock it as shown below:

```
UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();

for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    Label label = new Label();
    when(label.getUuid()).thenReturn(uuid));
    // ...
}
```

However, I get error:

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue: UUID cannot be
> returned by toString(). toString() should return String .

I think there is no need any conversion as both data types are `UUID`. How can I fix it?

**Update:**

```
public class Label extends BaseEntity {

    @Id
    private long id;

    private String key;
}
```

```
public abstract class BaseEntity{

    @NaturalId
    private final UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
}
```

I use label uuid in another entity (translatable) as shown below:

```
LabelTranslatable translatable = new LabelTranslatable();
translatable.setEntityUuid(textLabel.getUuid());
```

Comment: So what is the return type of your Label class's method getUuid()?

Comment: We need to see more code in order to be able to help you. The complete test class and also the actual class under test.

Comment: What is there on Label class?

Comment: Sorry, I added necessary code to Update.

Comment: And what is the code where getUuid is called?

Comment: @GauravJeswani I added last part of Update section.

Comment: You are trying to use when/thenReturn on an actual instance instead of a mock. You need `Label label = mock(Label.class);`

Comment: Focusing on the error message, "try": `...thenReturn(uuid.toString())..` (Posting/inspecting the "getter/setter portion of UUID" (== "the mocked code"!) would clarify more/always good;)